# SQL Server: Return object type of the objects found when searching for objects containing a string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that finds the given text in procedures/functions/triggers from selected DB (Not jobs):

```
Declare @SearchStr varchar(256) = 'MyStringToSearchFor'

SELECT 
       OBJECT_NAME(object_id), 
       OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) as SchemaName, 
       definition
FROM  
       sys.sql_modules
WHERE 
       definition LIKE '%'+@SearchStr+'%'
```

I would like this query to return the object type, for example, whether the found string is in a stored procedure, view, functions or trigger. Is it possible? If so, how could I modify the query to return this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` onto `sys.objects`:

```
DECLARE @SearchStr varchar(256) = 'MyStringToSearchFor';

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(m.object_id), 
       OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(m.object_id) as SchemaName, 
       m.definition,
       o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m
     JOIN sys.objects o on m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition LIKE '%'+@SearchStr+'%';
```